# My firefox is set to go through a proxy. How can I use this proxy in the terminal?

Tags: ssh, proxy

When I go into my settings page, I can get all the data on what firefox is using. I can go on github, download packages as zips, etc.

But when I use the terminal, to do git clone or ssh, the commands fail. I would imagine that getting simple bash commands to go through the same proxy that firefox is using should be *more* straightforward, but I can't figure it out.

Comment: What OS are you using?

Comment: ubuntu 14.04 is my OS

Answer (score 0):

If you're on Linux give it a try to setting HTTP_PROXY=somehost:port which is used by most programs. Unfortunately it's been a while since I last used a proxy to give it a try. It also depends on the specific program you'd like to use, if I recall wget has a somewhat different set up. And so does Java.